# Replying to comments

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

How do I reply to comments of users whose name contains characters not normally found in English?

For example:

1. Upside down letters
2. Symbols not present in keyboard
3. Maybe name in a different language etc...

I mean I have to type their name to reply, how do I do it?

Edit:

Is there a way other than copy and paste to do this?

Comment: Copy-and-paste?

Comment: Even with `@` you need to type in 3 characters for auto completion @Qantas 94 Heavy

Comment: @AI E. Ah, that is one solution I did not think of! Is there a way other than that?

Comment: @OneFace: I thought I remembered that if they had unicode-only names it was like that. Let me check it out...

Comment: Great question! I was going to ask it myself, because I couldn't reply to a person with an upside down name!  I'll be looking forward to seeing what you find, @Qantas94Heavy

Comment: @Sue: sorry, my bad. It works that way in the chat -- it shows up the names of all users with a first letter that cannot be typed. I don't know why it's not like that on the main site also.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thanks for checking. I'll be hoping this post will encourage someone to create it. For me, I use the iPad, which makes copy/paste more difficult. Also, I've noticed an influx of character-type names, especially on our language sites. As this question suggests, I think it would help those folks have an easier time here. I'm still trying to figure out how users turn their names upside down!

Comment: I use nexus 10 and my mobile phone, so it is difficult for me too to copy and paste. Thanks for checking @Qantas94Heavy. Plus auto completion is not implemented in mobile website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On desktop, the easiest way would be to copy-and-paste the username (or just the start of it) which you can paste after the @.

On mobile, the easiest way would be via the app, as it recognizes the @ and suggests users in the current "comment thread":

[image]

It's far more difficult on the standard mobile version of the site via a mobile device. Doable via the same method described for desktop, but difficult.

Comment: Reference: [How to trigger the auto-completion in a comment when referring to a non-latin user name?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2779/5764)

Comment: Desktop also suggests it by itself, if not then it's a bug.

Comment: i knew about the app. Was just wondering how to do it easily in the mobile website